# Suppress warning messages from MySQL in shell script but allow errors

Tags: shell-script, logs, io-redirection, mysql

My log files are getting dumped with following message while running shell scripts using some underlying MySQL commands.

Here is the message:

> "Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure."

To stop these messages, I am using the following job definition.

Example:

```
run_wrapper.sh |grep -v "Warning: Using a password" > output.log 2>&1
```

This worked but the MySQL errors are not being logged to `output.log`.

If I change the definition like the following, then MySQL errors start appearing if any

```
run_wrapper.sh > output.log 2>&1
```

So the question is how to suppress the warning messages and also report SQL errors in log files using only the cron definition?

Comment: probably you should use `run_wrapper.sh >> output.log 2>&1`

Comment: I'm not following. Where would you want error/warnings to go and where would you want output to go, and what would you want to throw away?  What is generating the password warning and why do you have errors in the MySQL that you don't want to fix?

Comment: mysql prints that warning when you use the `-p` option on the command line.  Instead of fixing it (e.g. by creating a `~/.my.cnf` with 600 perms) the OP wants to just ignore and discard the warning (and only that warning, not all of stderr)

Answer (score 31):

In your bash script, edit it at top

```
export MYSQL_PWD=yourdbpassword
```

and mysql query like: `mysql -u username -h host db -e "statement"`

**Reference:** From answer posted at [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20751352/suppress-warning-messages-using-mysql-from-within-terminal-but-password-written#24188878). Other answers can also be followed.

Answer (score 4):

search for a line in your wrapper similar to

```
mysql -u<username> -p<some_password> -hlocalhost -D<database_name>
```

and change to

```
export MYSQL_PWD=<some_password> ; mysql -u<username> -hlocalhost -D<database_name>
```

this solves the source of the warning.

Comment: This makes sense :-) Thx!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're missing the *stderr* redirection from `run_wrapper.sh` itself, so the errors aren't going through the `grep` and thence to the log file.

Try this instead if you're happy to have both *stdout* and *sdterr* written to your logfile

```
run_wrapper.sh 2>&1 | grep -v "Warning: Using a password" > output.log
```

Or if you want only the errors written to the logfile, and *stdout* left writing to the calling terminal, try this

```
( run_wrapper.sh 2>&1 1>&3 | grep -v "Warning: Using a password" > output.log ) 3>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```sh
lf='output.log'
> "$lf"   # first truncate/create the logfile.
run_wrapper.sh >> "$lf" 2> >(grep -v "Warn.*passw.*insec" >> "$lf")
```

Redirects stderr via [Process Substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution) to `grep -v ...`, and output from that is appended with `>>` to `output.log`

You probably want to use (GNU) `grep`'s `--line-buffered` option as well as `-v` to make sure error output isn't delayed.

---

If post-processing the log file is an acceptable option for you, you could just delete the unwanted "Warning: " line(s) from the log file after `run_wrapper.sh` has finished.

The following shell script fragment saves the timestamp (in `$ts`) of the log file (in `$lf`) before running `sed -i` and restores it afterwards:

```sh
lf='output.log'

run_wrapper.sh >& "$lf"

ts=$(date -r "$lf" '+%Y%m%d%H%M.%S')
sed -i -e '/Warning: Using a password/d' "$lf"
touch -t "$ts" "$lf"
```

If you need to preserve the inode of the log file (e.g. because it has hard links), use `ed` rather than `sed`:

```sh
ts=$(date -r "$lf" '+%Y%m%d%H%M.%S')
printf "%s\n" 'g/Warning: Using a password/d' w | ed -s "$lf"
touch -t "$ts" "$lf"
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have tried the suggested option like below

Comment: sed  option creates blank lines and we need to remove them also and it changes file timestamp also

Comment: The post-process-with-sed option also changes the inode as well as the timestamp - that's normal for `-i` (and most forms of "in-place" editing").  If run immediately afterwards, it should only be microseconds or seconds different, depending on logfile size of course.  But there's no way a `d` (delete line) command in `sed` will *create* a blank line - what exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: @jagadishpuvvada `sed` option now saves and restores output.log's timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the end of your command:

> /dev/null 2>&1